# How to determine origin of traffic to my web site

Tags: asp.net, security

I have an ASP.NET site where I use session variables to track sessions of Admins and Business members. I've encountered a bug where if the admin copies their URL and pastes it in an email, then if a user that has never logged in before clicks it, they will be redirected to the site logged in as an admin. This is a very big security concern. How can I tell if a user has been directed to the site from outside of the domain, and then redirect them to the site as a fresh member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surprises me that ASP.NET allows for session IDs to be transmitted as part of the URL.  This is horribly insecure.

As you have noticed, when you include the session ID as part of the URL any copy and pasted URL will include that session data.  You can try to work around this and determine if a user is clicking a link or actually traversing the site, but any of these methods will be able to be countered by malicious users.

You may try to argue that a user won't send their URL to a malicious user.  First of all, users will do a lot of silly thing, and they most certainly will copy and paste the URL to others.  Second, URLs are logged all over the place and will be available to anyone with access to those logs.

The correct way to handle sessions in ASP.NET is via Session State cookies, which will not be transferred via copy/paste or logged in places they shouldn't be.  According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx#vbtchaspnetcookies101anchor11) page, ASP.NET should default to using cookies instead of the URL based sessions, so it would seem that something you have done has caused them to be used.

Configure your application to use Cookie based sessions instead of trying to hack around the URL based sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a map between a session variable and its creator ip? If so, you can validate each use of session variable is performed by its creator ip. If ips are different, redirect it as a fresh member

Answer (score 0):

"You can reduce the chance of session data being shared by configuring the application not to recycle session identifiers. To do this, set the regenerateExpiredSessionId attribute of the sessionState configuration element to true. This generates a new session ID when a cookieless session request is made with an expired session ID."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx